# How to get the Deployment method in Azure for Self-Hosted Integration runtime?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I want to get the deployment method using Powershell for Self-Hosted Integration Runtime.
The requirement is to track whether the SHIR is installed using "Powershell" commands Or its done through the Azure Portal by a human user by manual steps.
Is there any Flag in Azure which indicates the method of the resource deployment? i.e. if its a PowerShell/ARM template/Portal deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-Hosted Integration runtime is a service installed on a windows operating machine (the only OS supported now) either on cloud(VM) or on-prem. Closest you can get to its details is under Applications and Services Logs on system Event Viewer, here you can Filter Logs for timestamp between Start and End of your ADF Pipeline.

Additionally, if you feel this is not helpful, you can share your [Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-azure-data-factory) so the product team can look into this idea. ✌

Comment: Hi Karthik - yes this will be a feature request as there is no option to identify "the SHIR creation in ADF and installation in VM" through any flag for the type of deployment. Or there is no policy which avoids manual creation of SHIR.

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer or accept my response. This can be beneficial to other community members.